# Flow Based Programming

Tags: language-agnostic, paradigms

I have been doing a little reading on [Flow Based Programming](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/) over the last few days.  There is a [wiki](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl) which provides further detail.  And wikipedia has a [good overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming) on it too.  My first thought was, "Great another proponent of lego-land pretend programming" - a concept harking back to the late 80's.  But, as I read more, I must admit I have become intrigued.

1. Have you used FBP for a real project?
2. What is your opinion of FBP?
3. Does FBP have a future?

In some senses, it seems like the holy grail of reuse that our industry has pursued since the advent of procedural languages.

Comment: @brice, yes, unix pipes are considered a form of (albeit a subset of) flow based programming!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Interesting discussion!  It occurred to me yesterday that part of the confusion may be due to the fact that many different notations use directed arcs, but use them to mean different things.  In FBP, the lines represent bounded buffers, across which travel streams of data packets.  Since the components are typically long-running processes, streams may comprise huge numbers of packets, and FBP applications can run for very long periods - perhaps even "perpetually" (see a 2007 paper on a project called Eon, mostly by folks at UMass Amherst).  Since a send to a bounded buffer suspends when the buffer is (temporarily) full (or temporarily empty), indefinite amounts of data can be processed using finite resources.

By comparison, the E in Grafcet comes from Etapes, meaning "steps", which is a rather different concept.  In this kind of model (and there are a number of these out there), the data flowing between steps is either limited to what can be held in high-speed memory at one time, or has to be held on disk.  FBP also supports loops in the network, which is hard to do in step-based systems - see for example http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?BrokerageApplication - notice that this application used both MQSeries and CORBA in a natural way.  Furthermore, FBP is natively parallel, so it lends itself to programming of grid networks, multicore machines, and a number of the directions of modern computing.  One last comment: in the literature I have found many related projects, but few of them have all the characteristics of FBP.  A list that I have amassed over the years (a number of them closer than Grafcet) can be found in http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?FlowLikeProjects .

Answer (score 27):

> *1. Have you used FBP for a real project?*

We've designed and implemented a DF server for our automation project (dispatcher, component iterface, a bunch of components, DF language, DF compiler, UI). It is written in bare C++, and runs on several Unix-like systems (Linux x86, MIPS, avr32 etc., Mac OSX). It lacks several features, e.g. sophisticated flow control, complex thread control (there is only a not too advanced component for it), so it is just a prototype, even it works. We're now working on a full-featured server. We've learnt lot during implementing and using the prototype.

Also, we'll make a visual editor some day.

> *2. What is your opinion of FBP?*

*2.1. First of all, dataflow programming is* ***ultimate fun***

When I met dataflow programming, I was feel like 20 years ago, when I met programming first. Altough, DF programming differs from procedural/OOP programming, it's just a kind of programming. There are lot of things to discover, even sooo simple ones! It's very funny, when, as an experienced programmer, you met a DF problem, which is a very-very basic thing, but it was completely unknown for you before. So, if you jump into DF programming, you will feel like a rookie programmer, who first met the "cycle" or "condition".

*2.2. It can be used only for specific architectures*

It's just a hammer, which are for hammering nails. DF is not suitable for UIs, web server and so on.

*2.3. Dataflow architecture is optimal for some problems*

A dataflow framework can make magic things. It can paralellize procedures, which are not originally designed for paralellization. Components are single-threaded, but when they're organized into a DF graph, they became multi-threaded.

Example: did you know, that **make** is a DF system? Try *make -j* (see man, what -j is used for). If you have multi-core machine, compile your project with and without -j, and compare times.

*2.4. Optimal split of the problem*

If you're writing a program, you often split up the problem for smaller sub-problems. There are usual split points for well-known sub-problems, which you don't need to implement, just use the existing solutions, like SQL for DB, or OpenGL for graphics/animation, etc.

DF architecture splits your problem a very interesting way:

- the dataflow framework, which provides the architecture (just use an existing one),
- the components: the programmer creates components; the components are simple, well-separated units - it's easy to make components;
- the configuration: a.k.a. dataflow programming: the configurator puts the dataflow graph (program) together using components provided by the programmer.

If your component set is well-designed, the configurator can build such system, which the programmer has never even dreamed about. Configurator can implement new *features* without disturbing the programmer. Customers are happy, because they have personalised solution. Software manufacturer is also happy, because he/she don't need to maintain several customer-specific branches of the software, just customer-specific configurations.

*2.5. Speed*

If the system is built on native components, the DF program is fast. The only time loss is the message dispatching between components compared to a simple OOP program, it's also minimal.

> *3. Does FBP have a future?*

Yes, sure.

The main reason is that it can solve massive multiprocessing issues without introducing brand new strange software architectures, weird languages. Dataflow programming is easy, and I mean both: component programming and dataflow configuration building. (Even dataflow framework writing is not a rocket science.)

Also, it's very economic. If you have a good set of components, you need only put the lego bricks together. A DF program is easy to maintain. The DF config building requires no experienced programmer, just a system integrator.

I would be happy, if native systems spread, with doors open for custom component creating. Also there should be a standard DF language, which means that it can be used with platform-independent visual editors and several DF servers.

Comment: What makes DataFlow or Flow-Based Programming in general bad for web servers?  Also how does Error Handling (and in general, "promises" & I/O) work?

Comment: Dataflow processing is "one-way". When a component receives a packet, it passes (the original packet, the modified one, or just some values picked from it etc.) to the next component. In case of a web server, or other service-like jobs, the response should be passed *back* to the sender at the end of processing chain, so response channel handle/ID should be passed thru all components, or alongside the processing path and join at the last step, in order to deliver result to the caller.

Comment: Error handling is easier, the processing component should have not only "result" but an "error" producer, so you can set up the error handling subgraph. The logging is similar issue, the component should have "log" producer, which you can wire to your logging component or just a printout component.

Answer (score 8):

I do have to disagree with the comment about FBP being just a means of implementing FSMs: I think FSMs are neat, and I believe they have a definite role in building applications, but the core concept of FBP is of multiple component processes running *asynchronously*, communicating by means of streams of data chunks which run across what are now called bounded buffers.  Yes, definitely FSMs are one way of building component processes, and in fact there is a whole chapter in my book on FBP devoted to this idea, and the related one of PDAs ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iF73.jpg)) - http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/compil.htm - but in my opinion an FSM implementing a non-trivial FBP network would be impossibly complex.  As an example the diagram shown in 
[image: http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/image010.jpg]
is about 1/3 of a *single* batch job running on a mainframe.  Every one of those blocks is running asynchronously with all the others.  By the way, I would be very interested to hearing more answers to the questions in the first post!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iF73.jpg): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton Push-down automata

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I hear the term flow based programming I think of LabView, conceptually.  Ie component processes who's scheduling is driven primarily by a change to its input data.  This really IS lego programming in the sense that the labview platform was used for the latest crop of mindstorm products. However I disagree that this makes it a less useful programming model.

For industrial systems which typically involve data collection, control, and automation, it fits very well.  What is any control system if not data in transformed to data out?  Ie what component in your control scheme would you not prefer to represent as a black box in a bigger picture, if you could do so.  To achieve that level of architectural clarity using other methodologies you might have to draw a data domain class diagram, then a problem domain run time class relationship, then on top of that a use case diagram, and flip back and forth between them.  With flow driven systems you have the luxury of being able to collapse a lot of this information together accurately enough that you can realistically design a system visually once the components are build and defined.

One question I never had to ask when looking at an application written in labview is "What piece of code set this value?", as it was inherent and easy to trace backwards from the data, and also mistakes like multiple untintended writers were impossible to create by mistake.

If only that was true of code written in a more typically procedural fashion!

Answer (score 4):

1) I build a small FBP framework for an anomaly detection project, and it turns out to have been a great idea.

You can also have a look at some of the [KNIME videos](http://www.knime.org/), that give a good idea of what a flow based framework feels like when the framework is put together by a great team. Admittedly, it is batch based and not created for continuous operation.

By far the best example of flow based programming, however, is **UNIX pipes** which is one of the oldest, most overlooked FBP framework. I don't think I have to elaborate on the power of nix pipes...

2) FBP is a very powerful tool for a large set of problems. The intrinsic parallelism is a great advantage, and any FBP framework can be made completely network transparent by using adapter modules. Smart frameworks are also absurdly fault tolerant, and able to dynamically reload crashed modules when necessary. The conceptual simplicity also allows cleaner communication with everybody involved in a project, and much cleaner code.

3) Absolutely! Pipes are here to stay, and are one of the most powerful feature of unix. The power inherent in a FBP framework compared to a static program are many, and trivialise change, to the point where some frameworks can be reconfigured *while running* with no special measures.

***FBP FTW! ;-)***

Answer (score 4):

In automotive development, they have a language agnostic messaging protocol which is part of the MOST specification (Media Oriented Systems Transport), this was designed to communicate between components over a network or within the same device. Systems usually have both a real and visualized message bus - therefore you effectively have a form of flow based programming.

That was what made the light bulb go on for me several years ago and brought me here. It really is a fantastic way to work and so much more fun than conventional programming. The message catalog form the central specification and point of reference. It works well for both developers and management. i.e. Management are able to browse the message catalog instead of looking at source.

With integrated logging also referencing the catalog to produce intelligible analysis things can get really productive. I have real world experience of developing commercial products in this way. I am interested in taking things further, particularly with regards to tools and IDEs. Unfortunately I think many people within the automotive sector have missed the point about how great this is and have failed to build on it. They are now distracted by other fads and failed to realize that there was far more to **most** development than the physical bus.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Spring Web Flow](http://static.springframework.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/index.html) extensively in Java Web applications to model (typically) application processes, which tend to be complex wizard-like affairs with lots of conditional logic as to which pages to display.  Its incredibly powerful.  A new product was added and I managed to recut the existing pieces into a completely new application process in an hour or two (with adding a couple of new views/states).

I also looked into using [OS Workflow](http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/) to model business processes but that project got canned for various reasons.

In the Microsoft world you have [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/) ("WWF"), which is becoming more popular, particularly in conjunction with [Sharepoint](http://www.microsoft.com/Sharepoint/default.mspx).

FBP is just a means of implementing a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine).  It's nothing new.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that it is not exactly the same thing, but this model has been used for years in PLC programming. ISO calls it Sequential Flow Chart, but many people call it Grafcet after a popular implementation. It offers parallel processing and defines transitions between states.

Answer (score 0):

It's being used in the Business Intelligence world these days to mashup and process data. Data processing steps like ETL, querying, joining , and producing reports can be done by the end-user.  I'm a developer on an open system - [ComposableAnalytics.com](http://composableanalytics.com) In CA, the flow-based apps can be shared and executed via the browser.

Answer (score -2):

This is what MQ Series, MSMQ and JMS are for.

This is cornerstone of Web Services and Enterprise Service Bus implementations.

Products like TIBCO and Sun's JCAPS are basically flow-based without using this particular buzz-word.

Most of the work of the application is done with small modules that pass messages through a processing network.