# How does a single threaded engine such as noflo implement flow based programming?

Tags: multithreading, noflo

Paul Morrison says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405627/flow-based-programming)

> the core concept of FBP is of multiple component processes running
>   asynchronously, communicating by means of streams of data chunks which
>   run across what are now called bounded buffers.

So, how does a single threaded implementations such as noflojs built on node.js simulate multiple concurrent asynchronous processes?  And can the same method be used in other single threaded languages?

Comment: Please add some details that allows more tight overview. Right now there are too many possible answers for this question.

Comment: One possible answer would be nice.

Comment: There is only one possible answer since I'm asking about a particular implementation, and also waiting for the author of noflo who is on SO to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the scope of the question is.

But I can tell you that Node.js is based on the [Reactor Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern).

It is possible to emulate this pattern in any single-threaded language implementation, assuming an adequate eventing model.  But this means any long-running process must be delegated to, send an event back when ready...with the reactor just brokering the exchange.